# How to set up fixtures for many-to-many through association (with values for the intermediary model)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, has-and-belongs-to-many, fixtures

`Organization` and `User` have a `many-to-many` relationship through `Relationship`. I read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html) about setting up fixtures for a HABTM association:

```
#users.yml
one:
  organizations: one
  email: one@example.com
  ...

#organizations.yml
one:
  name: "Company A"
  ...
```

This should establish a relationship between the `organization` and `user` in the fixtures, and does not require `relationships.yml` thereby keeping the set-up nice and clean.

However, in my case I need to specify certain variables for the relationships. For example, in the `relationship` table a `moderator` boolean is set. How can I include such values in the fixtures? I know I could do this by using `relationships.yml` and create my relationships there (which is how I've currently implemented it). But not needing `relationships.yml` keeps it so much cleaner. Is there a way to set these variables for the relationships without `relationships.yml`? For example, something like:

```
#users.yml
one:
  organizations: one(moderator: true)
  email: one@example.com
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures simply won't support the inline syntax you're referring to. Fixtures are very limited, and don't even support, e.g., doing inline definitions for objects related via `has_many`. So, aside from committing a patch to Rails, you only have two options that I'd suggest:

1. Use `relationships.yml`, like you mentioned already. Or...
2. Use [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) instead of fixtures. Factories come with their own set of problems, but not being flexible isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this and thought about to just tried the way I expect it to work. And it worked.

Following situation:

`user has_and_belongs_to_many roles`

roles:

```
# test/fixtures/roles.yml
admin:
  name: admin

donator:
  name: donator

developer:
  name: developer
```

users:

```
# test/fixtures/users.yml
aim:
  reddit_uid: wwkxo
  reddit_name: Elektron1c97
  name: Aim
  sign_in_count: 100
  roles: [admin, developer]
```

Check in the rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.first.roles.pluck(:name)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "roles"."name" FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 828945678]]
=> ["admin", "developer"]
```

Comment: The question is about HABTM with additional attributes, a.k.a. HABTM through:... This is not that case.